# How to monitor a child process without signals?

Tags: c++, linux, signals, ipc

I would like for my parent process to be notified of errors/failures/termination that occurs in a child process.

I'm interested to know if this is possible without using signals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pick up the exit status of a child with [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) or [`wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html).  This will tell you whether the child died of natural causes (an `exit()` or equivalent), or unnatural causes (a signal, and whether a core was dumped).  You will need to be allowing SIGCHLD signals to reach your process, but the default behaviour is fine.

Other errors are not so easily found out; you'd need some IPC mechanism to relay the information.